# Can I get the matrix determinant using Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I read in the manual of Numpy that there is function `det(M)` that can calculate the determinant. However, I can't find the `det()` method in Numpy.

By the way, I use Python 2.5. There should be no compatibility problems with Numpy.

Answer (score 76):

You can use [`numpy.linalg.det`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html) to compute the determinant of an array:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: M = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

In [3]: print numpy.linalg.det(M)
Out[3]: -2.0000000000000004
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the determinate without rounding errors?

Answer (score 32):

For **large arrays** underflow/overflow may occur when using `numpy.linalg.det`, or you may get `inf` or `-inf` as an answer.

In many of these cases you can use `numpy.linalg.slogdet` ([see documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html)):

```
sign, logdet = np.linalg.slogdet(M)
```

where `sign` is the sign and `logdet` the logarithm of the determinant. You can calculate the determinant simply by:

```
det = np.exp(logdet)
```

For sparse matrices (2-D arrays), I highly recommend [another approach based on LU decomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60982033/832621).