# Why isn't my Python code for finding determinants working?

Tags: python, matrix, determinants

The following code in Python 3 is meant to return the determinant of any order matrix. It takes in a text file with the form :

> 3 6 8 9
>   9 -7 5 -7
>   2 0 8 0
>   8 9 -1 -1

I get no error, but it is giving the wrong answer. Any clue why? Thanks!

```
def determinant(inputFileName):  
    def cofactorExp(listOfRows):  
        if len(listOfRows) <= 2:  
            return (float(listOfRows[0][0]) * float(listOfRows[1][1])) - (float(listOfRows[0][1]) * float(listOfRows[1][0]))  
        else:  
            for i in range(len(listOfRows)):  
                tempList = listOfRows[:]  
                del tempList[i]  
                for x in range(len(tempList)):  
                    tempList[x] = tempList[x][1:]  
                det = ((-1) ** i) * float(listOfRows[i][0]) * cofactorExp(tempList)  
                return det  
    rows = []  
    for line in open(inputFileName):  
    rows append(line split(" "))  
    for item in rows:  
        if "\n" in item[len(item) - 1]:  
            item[len(item) - 1] = item[len(item) - 1][:-1]  
    return(cofactorExp(rows))
```

Comment: You can use numpy for this task, unless this is a homework assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462500/can-i-get-the-matrix-determinant-by-numpy

Comment: Work it out by hand and see where your function's calculations start to differ.

Comment: It's a homework assignment, but we were allowed to make code that does what we want. I can't use that though.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

Your open file command doesnt properly handle spaces before and after the data

```
rows = []
for line in open(inputFileName):  
   rows.append(line.split(" "))  
for item in rows:  
   if "\n" in item[len(item) - 1]:  
        item[len(item) - 1] = item[len(item) - 1][:-1]
```

when I ran the code on my made up matrix, the command return this

```
[['3', '6', '8', '9'], ['9', '-7', '5', '-7'], ['2', '0', '8', '0'], ['8', '9', '-1', '-1', '']]
```

Notice there is an empty element in the matrix. Dont forget to add periods when calling a command in an object

I recommend using the example for csv module http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
return det
```

seems to prematurely exit the function since the det is in the scope of the loop

Lastly, there is an easier method to solve and code the determinant

```
   (aei+bfg+cdh)-(ceg+bdi+afh)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import *
x=input("give order of square matrix")
a=[]
for i in range(x):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(x):
        y=raw_input("input a["+str(i)+"]["+ str(j)+ "] element")
        a[i].append(y)
b=array(a)


print b

def rem(cc):
    s=cc.shape
    y=[]
    for i in range(s[0]):
        y.append([])
        for j in range(s[0]):
            if i==0:
                continue
            elif j==x:
                continue
            else:
                y[i].append(cc[i][j])
    y.pop(0)          
    return array(y)

def det(bb):
    n=0
    s=bb.shape  
    if s==(1,1):
        return bb[0][0]
    else:
        for j in range(s[0]):
            x=j
            global x  
            p=int(bb[0][j])
            pp=int(det(rem(bb)))        
            k=p*pp
            n=n+((-1)**(j))*int(k)
    return n

print "value is ",det(b)
```

Comment: You should provide some info on what this code is all about, and how it might help answer the question!