# Determinant of a (large) 1554 x 1554 matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to calculate the determinant of a large 1554,1554 matrix of values with single precision in python. In doing so I encounter a runtime warning:

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg as LA

a = np.random.random((1554, 1554))

b = np.random.random((1554, 1554))

c = np.dot(a,b)

det = LA.det(c)
```

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in det
>     r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)

Any ideas on how I can work around this problem? Many thanks!

Edit: this question is unique in that it specifically refers to computing the determinant of large matrix in double precision, though a possible answer is included here: [Can I get the matrix determinant using Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462500/can-i-get-the-matrix-determinant-using-numpy)

Comment: Why do you need the determinant?

Comment: Does it give you an overflow warning for smaller matrices?

Comment: @JamieMac check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19317237/832621)

Comment: @ Warren why not?

Comment: I am solving the Schlitter equation, for which I need to find the determinant

Comment: @nluigi I found that any matrices of 313x313 or larger return Inf.

Comment: Edit: I have found a previous answer to this question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462500/can-i-get-the-matrix-determinant-using-numpy). Thanks for your input and sorry for duplication!

Comment: To be fair your question is not a duplicate of the linked question even though one of the answers solves your specific problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this relation: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f6404a766d86e9d78a5c4f82e05de37469a5f8e9

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant

So divide your matrix by the mean and then compute the determinant to avoid overflow. Later you can multiply with the mean to the power of n (length of one axis)

edit: I'm not sure if the mean is the ideal choice though. This is more a math question

Comment: OP used np.random.random() to generate his matrices, meaning the mean will be about 0.5. Won't this make the computation *more* complicated?